# video problem with ie

Tags: html

I have a weird problem that I am not sure where to ask so I'll come here. Here is my test site wher the problem is - http://dev.nerdysyntax.com

My videos that are on my portfolio work page are not working properly in IE. Once you click on one of the videos, the next video seems to stick or freeze of some kind and I have to refresh to get them to work again. I thought this was due to a jquery lightbox plugin I had that overlayed my videos, but now I have them all embedded using a vimeo embed and still the same problem. This is very annoying and I have no solutions.

Comment: well I have IE9 on my other computer so I would say 9 and older

Comment: I took a quick look around on google. This appears to be a somewhat common problem, but no clear answer as to what's happening is available. Sorry I can't be more help - If your issue is what others describe, it would appear that your issue is not due to the code or assets you've put together, but instead a software issue in IE9.

Comment: Yea strange enough, it seems to be working in IE so far now. Not sure if it is the software issue or not. Hopefully it fixes itself because I have no clue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe you want to use different video player script and if that doesn't help, different video formats?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML5 `video` element, with Flash used for legacy systems. Video For Everybody (http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) is a great resource on how to do this cross-browser.

However, since you're specifically offering Flash video design this might not suit you, plus I believe Vimeo only serves up Flash video.

Comment: Yea I have seen the Video For Everybody website, but I'm not doing the HTML5 and Flash together. Just wondering if there is a problem with video and IE. There error seemed to stop later in that day, but I'm going to create a different layout for viewing those videos. Thanks.